# Are local method variables of a singleton thread safe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, singleton

I did find plenty of questions regarding singletons and thread safety, but none that quite answered this question for me... but I apologize if it is a repeat.

If I have a singleton object which will be used by multiple threads, I understand that any mutation to member variables should be carefully considered, but what about variables that are local to a method?

Consider this psuedo-code:

```
class Singleton  [assume this has all the trappings of a proper singleton]
{
    int doSomething() {
        SomeObject obj;
        obj.doStuff();
        return obj.result();
    }

}
```

In this case, is the local 'obj' thread safe?  Does each thread get its own copy of it, even though there is only one object of the Singleton class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `obj` is unique per thread.

There could be threading issues however if it accessed & modified common data - for example `doStuff` or `result` accesses a `static` member of `SomeObject` or some global.

Answer (score 0):

As Luchian said you are fine so far, however, if you have a static or any & or * variable, then try to use a mutex lock or a spin lock. Mutex locks and spin locks exist in all unix based systems, and I think you can use them in windows as well, but you need first to add them somehow.

Here is a link for pthread mutexes: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/c-mutex-examples/

And here another one for windows: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)